# How to Solve a set of equations

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I would like to solve the following two equations. For that I tried Findroot and solve function

```
Eq1 = ((-1)^(-1/c) *Gamma[(-1 + c)/c] *Gamma[1 - k])/
     Gamma[1 - 1/c - k]
    Eq2 = (-1)^(-1/c) *
      Gamma[(-1 + c)/
       c]*( Gamma[1 - 2 *k]/Gamma[1 - 1/c - 2 *k] -  Gamma[1 - k]/
        Gamma[1 - 1/c - k])
    
FindRoot[Eq1 == 3.05 && Eq2 == 0.34 , {c, 1.52}, {k, 0.005}]
```

But I am getting complex value as roots. But I want real numbers as solutions. Also I tries the following code,

```
sol = Module[{s = 0, 
   e = 0}, {FindRoot[{Eq1 == 4.325 && Eq2 == 0.0435}, {{c, 112}, {k, 
      0.000001}}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 4, StepMonitor :> s++, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> e++], "Steps" -> s, "Evaluations" -> e}]
```

I am not good in mathematica. can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The Gamma function is not a continuous function, so FindRoot may not work well. Your initial guesses would need to be pretty close. Plus, why do you expect the results to be real?

Comment: By removing (-1)^(-1/c) real roots are obtained. The Gamma functions are being multiplied by exp(- pi*i/c) and if c is not one then the results will complex, except in a few  cases.

Comment: @rhomboidRhipper I am dealing with quantile function. so I can consider only real parts.

Comment: What @Leucippus is saying, I think, is that it is impossible to have a solution in real numbers unless $c$ is the reciprocal of an integer, in fact, a negative integer for `Gamma[(-1 + c)/c]` to be defined.

Comment: From `ContourPlot[{Re[Eq1] == 3.05, Re[Eq2] == 0.34}, {c, -3, 3}, {k, -2, 
  2}, PlotPoints -> 50]` plot we see very large number of solution.If you whant only Real solution:`S = FindRoot[
  Re[Eq1] == 3.05 && Re[Eq2] == 0.34, {c, 9/10}, {k, 11/10}]` .We can check if solution is true: `{Re[Eq1], Re[Eq2]} /. S`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You're suggesting, in effect, that the problem should be stated `Eq1 = (Cos[\[Pi]/c]*Gamma[(-1 + c)/c]*Gamma[1 - k])/Gamma[1 - 1/c - k];
Eq2 = Cos[\[Pi]/c]*
   Gamma[(-1 + c)/c]*(Gamma[1 - 2*k]/Gamma[1 - 1/c - 2*k] - 
     Gamma[1 - k]/Gamma[1 - 1/c - k]);`, using `Cos[Pi/c]` instead of `(-1)^(-1/c)`?